# Remove double quotes from the substring preceding the first dot

Tags: regex, awk, sed, gnu

I previously asked the question in which I required help with removing double quotes from a string after a . (dot). I kindly received an answer however I am unsure as to how it works exactly.

I am now attempting to remove double quotes from around a string before the . (dot). I have attempted through trial and error to edit the original command, however I haven't had much luck, the closest I have come so far I have left below.

Could someone please explain how and why the first command works and if possible aid me editing my attempt to allow it to remove the double quotes from around the string on the left of the . (dot).

Original Command - removes " " from the right of the dot:

```
sed 's/\."\([^"]*\)"/.\1/g' file
```

Sample Before:

```
"A".HELLO
A."HELLO"
"A"."HELLO"
```

Required Result:

```
A.HELLO
A."HELLO"
A."HELLO"
```

Attempt:

```
sed -i 's/"*"\.\([^"]*\)"/.\1/g' $(2)
```

After:

```
"A".HELLO
A."HELLO"
"A.HELLO"
```

Link to original post: [UNIX Bash - Removing double quotes from specific strings within a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62266260/unix-bash-removing-double-quotes-from-specific-strings-within-a-file)
Credit to user potong for original answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(in case you are ok  with `awk`), written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {gsub(/"/,"",$1)} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Making field separator and output field separator as `.` in `BEGIN` section. Then in main program globally substituting `"` with NULL in first field specifically, since we have made `.` as field separator and OP wants to remove `"` double quotes before `.` only hence taking 1st field will do the trick here. `1` will print current line of Input_file.

Comment: I've never felt comfortable with awk as it always seemed quite intimidating! But that's a very clear explanation, thank you. I have tested that and it works. What other scenarios would you recommend using awk over sed?

Comment: @walkerja, IMHO experts(@Ed morton https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) they always recommend `awk` over `sed`(on complex and more logic involved tasks) because of `awk` is having more features which makes our life easy to implement in `awk` compare to `sed` cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.

Answer (score 1):

Using a primitive loop:

```
$ sed -e ':L' -e 's/\([^.]*\)"\([^.]*\.\)/\1\2/' -e 'tL' file
A.HELLO
A."HELLO"
A."HELLO"
```

This works with all POSIX-compliant seds, not only GNU sed.